# Avoid default 0 in xpages inputText

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have an xpages editbox control with display type as number and display format as currency.
By default this control shows 0.  But i want it to be null.  How do i achive this.
Also have another issue- control doesnt show currency format in read mode. It works fine in edit mode. How to get it work in read mode?

Here is the code:

```
<xp:inputText id="ApInt" value="#{dsRacDoc.ApInt}" 
dojoType="dijit.form.CurrencyTextBox" 
valueChangeListener="#{javascript:changeRequestBean.valueChangeListener}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="currency" integerOnly="true" currencySymbol="$">
        </xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="constraints" value="{fractional:false, max:999999999999999}">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="currency" value="USD">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="invalidMessage" value="Invalid amount. Enter whole dollar amount upto 15 digits">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
        <xp:dojoAttribute value="15" name="maxLength">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputText>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try with your code but if you remove *integerOnly* it should not default to 0 any more. The item value will be empty string. If you then set *maxFractionDigits* to 0 it should be the same as integer but I haven't tried this.

For read mode you may need to format it yourself in a *Computed Field*.

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution did work.  But there is another problem.  Now the default zero is gone and even the formating (with $ and thousand seperator) works fine in read mode.  But in edit mode the value is gone. I do see the value in back end which is of datatype number.

Comment: @lense Sounds strange. If you have a possibility to use extension library then `xe:djCurrencyTextBox` control might be the best fit for this.

Comment: Yes it seems strange. I couldnt figure out whats causing it. I am going to open a ticket with IBM, if i get any answer will post it here. I did try extenstion library control first. There seem to be a bug there. The fractional attribute is not working correctly. I dont want any decimal places. Setting fractional to false or decimal places to 0 doesnt work.

Comment: @lense You could still use the `fractional:false` dojo attribute. It works fine for me in `xe:djCurrencyTextBox`.

Comment: hmm...not sure what i am doing wrong. I am on 8.5.2, extension library control djCurrencyTextBox is forcing to enter decimals even though i specify fractional:false.

Comment: @lense It could be the Dojo or ExtLib version. I'm using 8.5.3FP3 with ExtLib 20121217. 8.5.2 has Dojo 1.4.3 and in 8.5.3 it's 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for this situation would be to have a separate edit and read view control as Panu already noticed.

Create 2 controls.

1. A simple  which will contain a expression in the value property which will generate the text format you want. for instance:

1. A second control which are will use in edit mode. This can be a arbritrary

Comment: Thanks.  This is what i am planning to do if nothing else works.  I have lot of currency fields so keeping this as last option. But at this point looks like this is the only option. Thanks for your response.